# Bootstrap datetimepicker does nothing, how can I sort out the dependencies?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I've seen the past struggles of people trying to get bootstrap datetimepicker to run, but I'm not sure if the solutions are a bit out of date.

I'm trying to get the basic datetimepicker example to run. Trying to bring in the dependencies with CDNs like so:

```
<head>
    <title>...</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/css" src ="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.2/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/css" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.43/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css"></script>
</head>
```

Then trying to implement the basic example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run this, the field that should be the date-time selection is just a normal text input, no calendar or time selection at all. No errors are generated, no "failed to load resource" or anything.

It seems like I've messed up the dependencies. This is probably obvious, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to call `datepicker` on the input, `$('#datetimepicker1 input').datetimepicker();`

Comment: What happens when you add a blank value to the `<input>`, i.e., `<input type="text" class="form-control" value="">`?

Comment: Chris Yongchu- thanks for your response. Calling datepicker on the input helped- I now have some date selection, but it doesn't look or behave like it should (http://i.imgur.com/6gOdm96.png) instead of (http://i.imgur.com/40VUkf7.png). 
Adding a blank value to the <input> did not seems to have an effect.

Comment: That's because your datetimepicker.css is set in the `<script>` tag, it should be a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="...">`.

Comment: The same goes for your `bootstrap.min.css` file. All CSS files are referenced using `<link>` not `<script>`.

Comment: Thank you sir! I appreciate your help. I wonder why calling datepicker on the input, as you suggested, is omitted from the basic example at https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: The datetimepicker is triggered when clicking on the icon and not the input element. Probably would have worked as you had it, but I think you were clicking in the input element. See `No Icon (input field only):` section of document, the selector is the `<input>`.

Comment: Either way, it's working now. See ya. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

id was given to div tag just give to input field

```
<input type='text' class="form-control" id='datetimepicker1' />
```